# Recurse JSON array of objects and arrays and get next obj property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, recursion

What I am trying to do is recursively loop through the "comments" in the JSON below and each time it finds something that is NOT an object, for now just an alert or console.log will do, the two pieces of data associated with the two object properties at once instead of looping through the recursive loop and getting each piece separately. I can do it that way BUT what I would like to do is get both data at once and then call the recursive loop with the NEXT obj (if one exists). What this means is that somehow I will need to keep track of a next obj and/or a parent obj and that is where I am having trouble. I thought that maybe somehow sending in a `next_obj_key` would be the way to go but I can't figure out how to grab that info so it is commented out.

I already have the code to call the function with just the comments.

Here is the code currently:

```
function loopIt(x, next_obj_key) {
  //next_obj_key = next_obj_key || 0;

  if (typeof x == "object") {
    last_obj = x;
    for (var attr in x) {
      loopIt(x[attr]);
    }
  } else {
    // Not an object, ignore
    alert("last_obj[0]: " + last_obj[0] + " --> last_obj[1]: " + last_obj[1] + " --> last_obj[MAX_ROWS]: " + last_obj['MAX_ROWS']);
    /*for (var attr in last_obj) {
        // Recursive call
        alert(last_obj[attr]);
    }*/
  }
  return blah;
}
```

... and here is the JSON I'm working with:

```
{
  "Success": [{
    "0": [{
      "customer_name": "DOE, JOHN",
      "company_name": "CLIENT COMPANY NAME HERE",
      "zip": "00000",
      "city": "NEW YORK",
      "state": "NEW YORK",
      "job_number": "XXXXXXXX",
      "skus": [{
        "0": "SKU 1",
        "1": "SKU 2"
      }],
      "comments": [{
        "0": [{
          "0": [{
            "0": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "11/01/2008 : "
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Completion date"
              }]
            }],
            "1": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Note"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "DELIVERED MERCHANDISE"
              }]
            }]
          }],
          "MAX_ROWS": "2",
          "MAX_COLS": "2"
        }],
        "1": [{
          "0": [{
            "0": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Dispatched To:"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "BOB SMITH"
              }]
            }]
          }],
          "MAX_ROWS": "1",
          "MAX_COLS": "2"
        }],
        "2": [{
          "0": [{
            "0": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Additional instructions"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "CLIENT REQUEST A CALL"
              }]
            }]
          }],
          "MAX_ROWS": "1",
          "MAX_COLS": "2"
        }],
        "3": [{
          "0": [{
            "0": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "",
                "1": ""
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "FROM"
              }],
              "2": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "TO"
              }]
            }],
            "1": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "area_code"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "xxx"
              }],
              "2": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "xxx"
              }]
            }],
            "2": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "",
                "1": ""
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "FROM"
              }],
              "2": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "TO"
              }]
            }],
            "3": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "value1"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "xxx"
              }],
              "2": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "xxx"
              }]
            }],
            "4": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "",
                "1": ""
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "FROM"
              }],
              "2": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "TO"
              }]
            }],
            "5": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "value2"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "xxxx"
              }],
              "2": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "xxxx"
              }]
            }]
          }],
          "MAX_ROWS": "6",
          "MAX_COLS": "3"
        }],
        "4": [{
          "0": [{
            "0": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Order Booked"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": [
                  {}
                ]
              }]
            }],
            "1": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Tech Name"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "TEST TECH NAME"
              }]
            }],
            "2": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Installer"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "TERRITORY HERE"
              }]
            }],
            "3": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Install Date"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "11/01/2008 AM"
              }]
            }],
            "4": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Start Time"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "08:00 AM"
              }]
            }],
            "5": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "End Time"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "12:00 PM"
              }]
            }]
          }],
          "MAX_ROWS": "6",
          "MAX_COLS": "2"
        }],
        "5": [{
          "0": [{
            "0": [{
              "0": [{
                "0": "label",
                "1": "Source"
              }],
              "1": [{
                "0": "text",
                "1": "External Client Tool"
              }]
            }]
          }],
          "MAX_ROWS": "1",
          "MAX_COLS": "2"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply change the object in loopit

kind of:

```
function loopIt(x,parent)
{
    //next_obj_key = next_obj_key || 0;

    if (typeof x == "object")
    {
        x.parent = parent;
        last_obj = x;

        for (var attr in x)
        {
            loopIt(x[attr],x);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Not an object, ignore
        alert("last_obj[0]: " + last_obj[0] + " --> last_obj[1]: " + last_obj[1] + " --> last_obj[MAX_ROWS]: " + last_obj['MAX_ROWS'] );
        /*for (var attr in last_obj)
        {
            // Recursive call
            alert(last_obj[attr]);
        }*/
    }
return blah;
}
```

doing the x.parent step.. you can simply keep checking the parents until it is null... so you will know you've reached the top of the food chain.

is that what you seek?

Comment: I think that is close. I tried loopIt(x,x.parent) and loopIt(last_obj,x.parent); in the else under the alert statement and it keeps alerting the same thing: x: label 
last_obj[0]: label
last_obj[1]: Completion date. So, I guess I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I apologize but I guess what I need to do is get the next obj,if there is one, and use that in the recursive call in the else statement. That way it will advance through.

Comment: Can you just tell wich part of the json you want in the end?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is build a separate table for each of the comments where a label/text/to/from is a td and then another td for the corresponding value. So a "label" of "note" would put "note" in the td and then the corresponding "text" would put "delivered to" (or whatever the value happens to be) in another td. Thanks for responding and I hope it is clear as I am a bit confused by it all.

Comment: If you need any more help... it's just ask :)